# Vertx Ext not getting imported

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x

I am getting errors while import vertx.ext in java and kotlin.
Have included the latest vertx-ext in my pom file.
Error Message :- Cannot resolve symbol ext.
Have included the following code for dependency inside the pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-ext</artifactId>
    <version>38</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Please help how to solve this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using vertx-ext?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Which IDE are you using? What else did you try? At what phase are you getting that error message?

There are a lot of 'Cannot resolve symbol' maven questions and answers on SO. Try referencing them and re-editing your question with more details of your problem.